# Is rpcbind needed for an NFS client?

Tags: linux, nfs, rpcbind

I understand that `rpcbind` runs on NFS servers to respond to port-mapping requests from clients.

**Is the `rpcbind` daemon needed on an NFS *client*?**

I'm surprised that it is so difficult to find a definitive answer to this question. That might be because there's no reason to suspect that it *is* required.

The reason I'm asking is because I found that `rpcbind` is running on a number of Debian servers that are not NFS servers. And surprisingly, the [`nfs-common`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/nfs-common) package directly depends on `rpcbind`, even though:

> Use this package on any machine that uses NFS, either as client or server.

Related Serverfault questions:

- [NFS client firewall settings and rpcbind](https://serverfault.com/questions/949127/nfs-client-firewall-settings-and-rpcbind)

  > I don't understand why nfs-common depends on rpcbind if it works without it. Am I missing anything ? Maybe rpcbind is needed for file locking or nfs stats.
- [Can rpcbind packagebe removed in debian wheezy, installed by default?](https://serverfault.com/questions/543800/can-rpcbind-packagebe-removed-in-debian-wheezy-installed-by-default#comment649531_543804)

  > Yes, you can safely remove rpcbind if you don't plan on using NFS on your server.
- [NFS client firewall settings and rpcbind](https://serverfault.com/questions/949127/nfs-client-firewall-settings-and-rpcbind)

  > `apt-cache depends nfs-common` gives `rpcbind` as a direct dependency.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The NFS client uses rpcbind service on server to discover the port number used by nfsd.

More over, for clients of nfs v2 and v3, an additional [rpc-statd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/rpc.statd) service is used to manage locks. As rpc-statd runs on the client, a  rpcbind should run on the client to let nfs servers to discover on which port rpc-statd listens.

Thus, for client that uses nfs v4, the rpcbind, rpc-statd and rpc-statd-notify services can be disabled. This can required modifying some .service files.

IOW - ***The rpcbind service is needed by nfs clients that use v2 and v3, as it required for file locking, and can be disabled for nfs v4 clients, as locking is a part of the NFSv4.0 protocol.***

Comment: I'm sorry, but this still does not answer my question. *"rpc-statd service is used to manage locks"* -- this is running on the server, right? I am asking if `rpcbind` needs to be running **on the client**.

Comment: The 'rpc-statd' runs on the client and used by nfs servers to send clients lock GRANT information or reboot notification.

Comment: Thank you. If you care to update your answer with that information (and ideally a reference to some further reading)  I'd be happy to award the bounty to you.

Comment: Ok. I have updated the answer. Let me know if more corrections are required.